# Issues with reading image pixels from file

Tags: python, image, byte, rgb, unsigned-integer

I understand that in Python there are multiple ways to get all of the pixels of an image, using external libraries like `PIL` or `Image`. Interested to try out my binary skills, I figured I'd go ahead and try to read the pixels in raw Python with the binary data from the file. This is the image I used as an example:

[image: The image I used in my program.]

What I gathered from other questions was that I needed to convert the bytes to a whole bunch of unsigned integers before processing. I used `struct.unpack` to do this. Here's my program so far:

```
import struct

with open('connect.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    print(struct.unpack("I"*int(len(data)/4), data))
```

This gives me a whole bunch of crazy integers. I figured these were just RGB integers that I had to convert, so I did that. A couple of issues here:

- The list of pixels was only 2019 long, while my image is 320x240.
- The pixel colors were horrendously off. I would have figured the first few thousand pixels would have been close to `rgb(0,0,0)`, but I was getting green, purple, yellow, red - everything.

For reference, here is the code I used to convert the unsigned integers into RGB tuples:

```
def rgb_int2tuple(rgbint):
    return (rgbint // 256 // 256 % 256, rgbint // 256 % 256, rgbint % 256)
```

I feel like I am taking the whole wrong approach here. Am I possible not reading the data into the right format, or is something messed up with my int-to-RGB function?

Comment: `jpg` are compressed, you need to use a library. If you want to learn new skills use skillshare. Just kidding see [this video](https://youtu.be/n_uNPbdenRs) to learn how jpg are stored.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte Is there a way to decompress them?

Comment: Yes but watch the video, that way you will know why it is a bad idea to try this without a library. You have to do a Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT).

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte You know, it's bad practice to just direct someone to a video.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that, but it is the best ressource out there, you can find plenty of Discrete Cosine Transform unreadable scientific papers. The best is probably [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) but I supposed that by giving you the name, you would have found it quickly.

Comment: What you can do too is look at PIL/PILLOW 's implementation, if you want to know how it's done.

Comment: The video I sent has great human-generated subtitles if you are in a situation in which you can't watch the video because of sound.

Comment: You should understand the .jpg file format. Wikipedia usually has a good summary and link to original standards (the summary is necessary to understand the standard, because of technicalities of standards). Reading code from some open source program also helps. Note: as you see there are many version/levels/options: not all readers will handle all case correctly [as you may encounter here on SO] -- note: it is not only the discrete cosine transformation, but all headers, interpretation of colours/channels, etc.